# word for a person that flirts with everyone?

Tags: single-word-requests

i am looking for a word to describe someone that flirts with everyone, even if they aren't attracted to that person and have no interest in carrying out anything further than flirtation?

Comment: Uh, how does a word flirt?

Comment: @JulieCarter — It would conform to the Stack Exchange model if you could answer as an answer, not as a comment. That way the OP could  accept your answer properly so that the question would be marked as answered. You would have to supply some documentation to support your answer, but that would allow others to judge whether it is or is not correct and allow it to be voted down as well as up. There is a reason for the injunction in the comment box.

Answer (score 10):

A word that is not too derogatory is simply *flirt*:

> one given to flirting; a person who acts flirtatiously. - AHDEL/Collins [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flirt)

Anything beyond that is beginning to judge or impute a motive which may or may not be true.

Some flirts are charming and funny people who enjoy making people feel good, and want people to like them. Who knows why they do it? Sometimes it's fun for both people.

Some flirts are never serious. This can be annoying, and you might call such a person superficial. If a person does it solely to amuse themselves, you might call them a [tease](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tease):

> a person who makes fun of or annoys others, as with playful or taunting remarks; A flirtatious person. - AHDEL/TFD

When people do it with bad motives - of which you're aware - then you can look for more appropriate labels. But all you've described in your question is *a flirt*.

Comment: It's also fairly gender neutral.  A good synonym for flirtatious is *coquettish*, though it's not generally applied to men.

Comment: @stevesliva - I agree. The biggest flirts I ever knew were guys.

Comment: Yup, that's the answer. A flirt flirts. Flirts flirt. Flirts flirt with flirts.

Answer (score 1):

A gender specific word is **coquette**.

Simple Definition

> a woman who likes to win the attention or admiration of men but does
>   not have serious feelings for them

"Coquette." Merriam-Webster.com. Accessed April 4, 2016. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coquette.

**Synonyms** of coquette

> flirt ...

Related Words

> vamp; ... tease; ... lead on, string along; manipulate, play (with)

"Coquet." Merriam-Webster.com. Accessed April 4, 2016. http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/coquet.

The final related word is "play," which is easily be converted to **player**. I doubt that "player" is superior to "flirt," though.

> A male who is skilled at manipulating ("playing") others, and
>   especially at seducing women by pretending to care about them, when in
>   reality they are only interested in sex.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=player&defid=867614

Answer (score 1):

it can be '[casanova](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=casanova)' also.....

> A smooth-talking charmer who has mastered the art of finding, meeting, attracting and seducing beautiful women into the bedroom. One he accomplishes his goal, he leaves the woman in fear of having a relationship and proceeds to find his next conquest.

(From Urban Dictionary.)

Answer (score 0):

A similar term to Casanova (above) is **Lothario**.

My iPhone Chambers app has

> Lothario /lō-thäˈri-ō or -thāˈ/
>   noun (pl Lotharˈios)
>   A seducer, a rake
>   ORIGIN: From Lothario, in Nicholas Rowe's play, The Fair Penitent (1703)