# When "play" has a sexual connotation, what type of sex does it refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, connotation

*Urban Dictionary* includes one explanation of "play" :

> Anything to do with sexual relations: fooling around, making out, oral sex or having intercourse.

However, most of the formal-language dictionaries don't include this explanation, only interpreting the word as "to tease" which can describe something childlike such as flirtation, except the phrase "play ground" meaning:

> Having sexual relations with other people who is not your partner.

Merriam-Webster Dictionary also suggests "play (n.)" as "flirtation", which can be converted into "flirt" with "play (v.)"

Is this a difference between the formal language and slang?

This question also leads to an answer which regards "play" as a synonym of "flirt".

[word for a person that flirts with everyone?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252309/word-for-a-person-that-flirts-with-everyone/317469#317469)

1. Does the slang term have a much broader meanings than the flirty activities implied in the formal language?
2. Does the term imply being unfaithful?

Comment: play ground? The UD is not a reliable source at all for this kind of thing.  When play refers to something sexual, as in "play around", it usually does not involve intercourse. "play around" is a colloquial phrasal verb.

Comment: Is there a difference between formal language and slang? Yes, and oh yeah.

Comment: @Lambie is right; if it's from Urban Dictionary and involves sex, take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Precisely defining slang terms is a difficult task.

Comment: Well, there is the old term *foreplay*, which implied that *the main event* was excluded.

Comment: "Play" is often used for casual sex, and in various specialised communities (gay, BDSM, etc) for various sexual and fetish practices, as UD says. "Play around" is often used for extramarital sex, as well as to refer to heavy petting/foreplay etc. Generally many sexual terms are used very loosely, or if they once referred to mild practices are used euphemistically for something more serious.

Comment: Personally, while I think the question could be better written, it seems OK: asking about the connotations of "play" in one or more contexts would be reasonable. It's probably better to have a narrow question rather than to ask for every meaning of "play", though. (I would like to see a rewrite before reopening, to focus on one question.)

Comment: @StuartF Thx for ur consideration! Take instance, the text given in my another post. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605527/what-does-he-was-a-child-who-couldnt-keep-his-fingers-out-of-the-cookie-jar-m

Comment: @StuartF I wonder if the term "played" in this context can imply something promiscuous, heavily sexual or even sexually criminal? As a non-native English speaker, I don't know whether the term can be linked with crime in the English culture.

Comment: Please edit your post to replace the picture of text with actual text.

Comment: Is something getting lost in translation perhaps? The suspect definition given for *play ground* would be appropriate for the phrase *play the field*.

Comment: @StuartF I don't spend my days frequenting sex communities, but I have never heard the word "play" on its own to mean have sex **per se**.

Comment: The question was “is this a difference between the formal language and slang”. Not really. M-W does slang. This is the difference between a reliable dictionary and one developed by people off the street. Urban Dictionary is not the product of lexicographers. The result is a mostly useless troll-fest of racism, misogyny, personal attacks, and bathroom humor. Avoid consulting Urban Dictionary when you have a real question. And unless such things truly entertain you, avoid it completely. Instead try *[Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/)*.

Comment: @Lambie  Thanks for your talk. I checked the word with the dictionary MetaEd shared. According to the explainations and examples there, play (n.) mostly refers to light sexual activities while some sentences shows play (v.) has the meaning of intercourse. I guess it is still a matter of frequency: while in our daily life "play" tends to mean "something just all in fun", there are someone who like to take it in a broader way.

Comment: @RomanGhost That dictionary basically says in the first entry what I said.

Comment: @Lambie It is obvious that play (n.) is a synonym of flirtation, which is well explained both in that dictionary and Webster. But maybe the meaning of the term changes a little when it is converted into play (v.).

Comment: @RomanGhost Of course, flirtation or being flirtatious. I don't understand "converted into play".

Comment: @Lambie As a English learner, I used to learn from a book that when a noun becomes a verb its meaning would sometimes extend or narrow and vice versa. I guess this theory may explain the nuance between play (n.) and play(v.). I remember an example in the dictionary: A boss exposed his genitals and said to his secretary,"come and play with me." This "play" obviously refers to intercourse. But, though the term's usage varies a little among individuals, I believe that the kind of "intercourse" play can stand for is amusing and game-like, not crime like forced intercourse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "play", with sexual overtones, is short for "play around" and that definition, well, I really think has a lot to do with the age and experiences of the individuals involved. Might be simply rolling in the grass touching each other and kissing, or, it could be heavy petting, rending of clothing and ending beyond "play".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It made sense a lot. By the way, the reason why I specially illustrated sexual crime is that "play" traditionally refers to something normally entertaining no matter it is linked with sex. Despite poor knowledge of English and cultural difference, I assume that the term in English does not mean something seriously devil and malignant, such as forced intercourse. (Hope for your reply.)

Comment: Suppose I should say individual or individuals, one can "play" with themself.